# CMake: Recommended way for a Config-File Package to depend on a Find-Module Package

Tags: build, cmake

I've just been reading about CMake's Config-File Package "concept" which sounds very promising. What I like very much about it is that if I create a Config-File Package myself I can specify other packages on which it depends. My Question is: How can I create a Config-File package that is "relocatable" and depends on a Find-Module Package (e.g. boost)?

In more detail: Suppose I want to create a package named HyDi. The [cmake documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#id15) explains then very nicely how I can create the corresponding HydiConfig.cmake and HydiTargets.cmake files automatically. A very simple version of the CMakeLists.txt that does this is:

```
project(HyDi)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS program_options)
add_library(HyDi foo.cpp foo.hpp)
target_include_directories(HyDi PUBLIC INTERFACE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(HyDi ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_compile_options(HyDi INTERFACE PUBLIC "-std=c++11")


install(TARGETS HyDi EXPORT HyDiTarget
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
  INCLUDES DESTINATION include
)

install(FILES foo.hpp DESTINATION include)

configure_file(cmake/HyDiConfig.cmake
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/HyDi/HyDiConfig.cmake"
  COPYONLY
)

set(ConfigPackageLocation lib/cmake/HyDi)
install(EXPORT HyDiTarget FILE HyDiTargets.cmake 
    NAMESPACE Upstream:: DESTINATION ${ConfigPackageLocation} )
install(FILES cmake/HyDiConfig.cmake DESTINATION ${ConfigPackageLocation})
```

The corresponding HydiConfig.cmake is:

```
include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)
find_dependency(Boost COMPONENTS program_options)

include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/HyDiTargets.cmake")
```

However if I install this library, the HyDiTargets.cmake file will contain the include path to the Boost Libraries hardcoded and is thus not relocatable.

Note that the [cmake documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#id15) gives an example of how not to include the boost libraries that is essentially my version. But they unfortunately don't explain how to do it better.

I understand that I could build boost using cmake and could then import boost as a Config-file package so that my HydiTargets.cmake would relocatable. But this approach doesn't work with every other library that provides a Findxxx.cmake file.

Comment: Thanks ruslo, but this solution implies essentially that I would have to build boost using cmake (which is still experimental)

Comment: okay I just took again a look at hunter and yes, for boost this would be an option. However I don't see how I could get a cmake package (config mode) for my seven other external libraries (unless a package exists in Hunter). Also I would like to avoid the use of 3rd party cmake tools if possible it all.

Comment: Very interesting question, I am facing the same issue. [craffael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2796908/craffael) have you come up with a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately i have not found a satisfactory solution until now. But i also have not looked at the issue in detail since about 2 years...

Answer (score -2):

Actually CMake doing this correct, when inject a "hardcoded" path to boost libraries (and you doing it wrong). Because after your library gets compiled and installed, it should "links" w/ very particular boost version (when it was at the moment of your library compilation) -- i.e. its header files and static/dynamic libraries.

Consider scenario: after successfull installation of your library, someone installs a new version of boost library (or any other third party library you depending on) in parallel (yeah, boost and some other libs could coexists in the same install prefix). To make things looks like a real world example, assume it is ABI incompatible w/ the previous version. Now if that "lucky" developer wants to use your (already compiled and installed) library (using exported targets and provided `HyDiConfig.cmake`) he'll get a trouble:

- your library **already** linked to a "previous" boost version (remember ABI incompatible w/ a newer one);
- so when you somehow replace that "hardcoded" paths and would find a newer version (as you trying to do in `HyDiConfig.cmake`) your "lucky" customer would angry on you for that mess!

That is not only about boost… same policy for all third party libraries: they should remains the same as it was at the moment of compilation (or at least ABI compatible if we are talking about dynamic linking at run time, but this is a separate story).

Moreover, your user probably even do not use boost in his app (but have more than one version installed) -- why you should find smth? You already **know** (thanks to CMake and hardcoded paths) what boost version "required" for your library! So finding smth new is completely wrong in this case! It is "too late… **Your library already compiled, linked and installed!**

Another case: he wants to use some other (newer) version of boost… Depending on order of `find_package(boost)` and `find_package(yourLib)` results may vary… but he'll be angry on you anyway!